# iOS simulator cannot connect to development server

Tags: ios, networking, ios-simulator

I am developing on MacOS XCode 12.3, simulator iOS 14.3 attempting to connect to a development server on a machine on the local network. I have an entry in `/etc/hosts` specifying the address of the development server. This used to work, and still works in Mac applications.

The app in the simulator **cannot access the server**. Safari in the simulator also cannot access the server.

The log shows `nil host used in call to allowsSpecificHTTPSCertificateForHost` and `nil host used in call to allowsAnyHTTPSCertificateForHost:`

I have set `Allow Arbitrary Loads` and `Allow Arbitrary Loads in Web Content` to true and added the server to `Exception Domains` in `Info.plist`.

How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the simulator no longer uses `/etc/hosts`. I set up a local DNS server `dnsmasq` and that allowed the simulator to access the server again.

See https://zhimin-wen.medium.com/setup-local-dns-server-on-macbook-82ad22e76f2a

Replace `<servername>` and `<ipaddress>` with your details.

```
> brew install dnsmasq
> cp /usr/local/etc/dnsmasq.conf /usr/local/etc/dnsmasq.conf.orig
> echo "conf-dir=/usr/local/etc/dnsmasq.d/,*.conf" > /usr/local/etc/dnsmasq.conf
> echo "address=/<servername>/<ipaddress>" > /usr/local/etc/dnsmasq.d/<servername>
> sudo mkdir -p /etc/resolver 
> echo "nameserver 127.0.0.1"> /etc/resolver/<servername>
> sudo brew services start dnsmasq
```

Test the DNS service:

```
> dig <servername> @localhost +short
> 192.168.20.21
```